# org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException Cannot open the connection for the driver

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, report, birt

I got error in run birt-runtime-4_5_0 using get report view, Then How I get successful out put?

**Error**

`org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException:` An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details: Cannot open the connection for the driver:`org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException:` Cannot load JDBC Driver class: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:249)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:273)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:89)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:159)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:118)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:103)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:671)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:83)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:285)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1947)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
... 81 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:177)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:437)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:179)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:651)
... 86 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.findDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:881)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.loadAndRegisterDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:986)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.loadAndRegisterDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:963)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:285)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:236)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:254)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:163)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
... 96 more
```

I think this error get in **jdbc Driver** there I use old project jdbc drive and mainReport.rptdesign create my normal project inside.Is it error ?

Comment: Have you upgraded to new version of BIRT recently? What jar with driver do you have on a classpath? Also, I can understand nothing from: "I think this error get in jdbc Driver there I use old project jdbc drive and mainReport.rptdesign create my normal project inside". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, Did you solved your problem ?